# What is the difference between install(FILES) and file(INSTALL)?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to move a file to a specific location, and I did it like this:

```
file(INSTALL file.txt DESTINATION ../install_dir)
```

This worked fine. This moved `file.txt` to the specified destination.

However then I tried like this:

```
install(FILES ./file.txt DESTINATION ./install_dir)
```

Using `install(FILES)` doesn't copy files like I expect. The file is not installed at that location when I run the CMake configure command.

Can someone please explain the difference to me? Why is it that `file(INSTALL)` works when running the configure command, but `install(FILES)` doesn't?

Comment: Do you want the file to be copied at *configure time* (when CMake is running and parsing your CMakeLists.txt files), or at *install time* (when running `make install` or equivalent)?

Comment: so that is the difference :D ty

Answer (score 8):

The two commands do different things. [`install(FILES fil DESTINATION dest)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) instructs CMake to generate a build rule so that file `fil` is copied into `dest` when running the install step (`make install` or equivalent).

[`file(INSTALL ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) is evaluated immediately at configure time, while CMake is parsing the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Note that this signature is primarily intended for CMake's internal implementation of the above mentioned installation step: it prints install-themed status messages etc. If you just want to copy a file at configure time, you might want to prefer `file(COPY)` or `file(COPY_IF_DIFFERENT)`.